# <Input type ="number"> should only accept positive integers

Tags: javascript, html

This HTML code still allows me to write **`.`**

So if a user writes `1.2` that will automatically be converted to `12`.

I don't want to allow the user to write `.` itself.

Also, though it doesn't allow the user to start with the `-` sign it allows the user to enter it in the middle like `21-` but then it immediately resets the entire field to blank.

How do I fix this so that it only accepts positive integers?

```html
<input type="number" min="30" max="300" step="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value=value.replace(/\D+/g, ''))" style="width:4em" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30" onmouseout="setBounds()" />
```

setBounds() has the functionality so the user can only enter between 30 and 300

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a `keypress` event handler for the element that checks the key that is being pressed and cancels the event upon the `.` or `-` entries with [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), like this:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("seconds");

// Set your event handlers up in JavaScript, not with
// inline HTML event attributes
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
 if(event.key === "." || event.key === "-"){
   event.preventDefault(); // Cancel the native operation
 }
});
```

```html
<input type= "number" min="30" max="300" step="1" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30">
```

But, because you have a specific range in mind, you may want to consider using an `input type="range"` which eliminates the potential for the problem in the first place:

```js
// Get reference to the input and the output elements
const input = document.getElementById("seconds");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

output.textContent = input.value;  // Initialize the output

// Set your event handlers up in JavaScript, not with
// inline HTML event attributes
input.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  output.textContent = this.value; // Update the output
});
```

```html
<input type= "range" min="30" max="300" step="1" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30">
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: I really like the range slider. But how would I get the final value of that range slider in a js function? Without waiting for a button to be pressed.

Comment: @befb You would get it the same way you would get any other `input` value, through it's `.value` property.